# Why I am seeing opposing trend in the partial PDF (pair distribution function) when compared to Total PDF?

Tags: radial-distribution-function, amorphous-materials

I am working with x$\ce{M_2O}$-(1-x)$\ce{SiO_2}$ binary glass having two different fractions of modifier (x=0.2 and 0.4). Glass with a 40% modifier has a higher density than glass with a 20% modifier. The intensity of the Si-O peak that corresponds to 40% of the modifier is less than the intensity that corresponds to 20% when plotting the total pair distribution function (PDF); however, the reverse trend has been seen when plotting the partial $\ce{Si-O}$ PDF. I don't understand why?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but just wanted to come back and check how things are going. Did you figure this out? Are you still working on it? Let us know!